# Do foster parents have to be included on the Australian visa application?

Tags: visas, australia, minors

I am a child, and live with my grandmother and uncle since my mother migrated to Australia. Should I list them on a visa application form that asks for details of parents, along with my mother's and father's details?

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity. Feel free to undo them if I have changed the meaning.

Comment: I agree with @pnuts. As a partial explanation, besides whatever other record checking that they will do about your family, asking in particular about your parents' citizenship and birthplace will have implications for your own potential citizenship(s); this would not be true for a foster situation. The country you wish to visit, whatever it is, is certainly interested in citizenship issues.

Comment: Given that OP is a child, it might not hurt including them (i.e. the foster parents) though, specified as such.

Comment: I'm almost certain that the OP used the phrase 'I am grown' rather than child; wouldn't that make a difference?

Comment: I don't think anyone's asked the right question of the OP. What visa are you applying for? A visitor's visa, 101, 802, immigration visa? If you are a minor, under 18, generally an adult or sponsor would fill out the form (and sign it) rather than you.

Comment: @pnuts go figure and, given the others being asked, OP is dancing around the actual issue; thx.

Comment: @pnuts indeed and, depending on the age, better to suggest local help, hopefully non-profit, so that they get it right.

Comment: @eboo What is the purpose of your trip to Australia?

Answer (score 2):

We don't know:

- OP's citizenship
- OP's residency
- the type of visa to be applied for

We do know that the fostering is *with my grandmother and uncle*. So taking a wild guess, this may be [kinship care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship_care) that does not involve legal custody of the child. In which case the people the OP is living with are not the OP's parents so are not eligible for inclusion as such on the application form.

If however they do have legal custody then they should be included (and not the biological parents, unless they hold joint custody).